# Tablesorter plugin, json format issue

Tags: json, format, tablesorter

```
[{"Id":"8082","Date":"2017-12-09 23:40:39"},{"Id":"7825","Date":"2017-12-09 23:40:17"},{"Id":"3138","Date":"2017-12-09 21:58:03"},{"Id":"4805","Date":"2017-12-09 21:25:01"},{"Id":"2570","Date":"2017-12-09 01:08:15"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-08 23:53:24"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-08 23:53:18"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-08 23:53:13"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-08 23:53:07"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-08 23:53:02"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-08 23:52:56"},{"Id":"7825","Date":"2017-12-08 23:40:01"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-07 23:53:00"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-07 23:52:54"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-07 23:52:48"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-07 23:52:42"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-07 23:52:36"},{"Id":"7832","Date":"2017-12-07 23:43:27"},{"Id":"8082","Date":"2017-12-07 23:40:54"},{"Id":"4805","Date":"2017-12-07 21:24:53"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-06 23:52:35"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-06 23:52:30"},{"Id":"7832","Date":"2017-12-06 23:43:05"},{"Id":"8082","Date":"2017-12-06 23:40:35"},{"Id":"7825","Date":"2017-12-06 23:40:13"},{"Id":"3841","Date":"2017-12-06 22:56:18"},{"Id":"3765","Date":"2017-12-06 22:38:20"},{"Id":"4805","Date":"2017-12-06 21:24:51"},{"Id":"2570","Date":"2017-12-06 01:08:16"},{"Id":"1397","Date":"2017-12-06 00:09:34"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-05 23:52:20"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-05 23:52:15"},{"Id":"8733","Date":"2017-12-05 23:52:08"},{"Id":"7832","Date":"2017-12-05 23:42:36"},{"Id":"7825","Date":"2017-12-05 23:39:42"},{"Id":"3138","Date":"2017-12-05 21:56:47"},{"Id":"4805","Date":"2017-12-05 21:24:41"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:44"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:39"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:33"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:28"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:22"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:17"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:11"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:05"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:11:00"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:10:55"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:10:48"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:10:43"},{"Id":"8291","Date":"2017-12-05 00:10:37"}]
```

This is the format of the php array outputs in json. I'm trying my best but unfortunately I can't load the data in tablesorter pager.. I have read almost every single stackoverflow topic related to this and Mottie's pager example. The problem I face seems to be the format of the json.

Is it possible to make tablesorter plugin to read through the json file that I have given example of?

In addition I use ajaxurl to load the file ajaxUrl (everything is loaded in the header):

```js
<script type="test/javascript">
$(function(){
  // Initialize tablesorter
  // ***********************
  $("myTable")
    .tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      widthFixed: true,
      sortLocaleCompare: true, // needed for accented characters in the data
      sortList: [ [0,1] ],
      widgets: ['zebra']
    })

    // initialize the pager plugin
    // ****************************
    .tablesorterPager({

      // **********************************
      //  Description of ALL pager options
      // **********************************

      // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
      container: $(".pager"),

      // If you want to use ajaxUrl placeholders, here is an example:
      // ajaxUrl: "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}"
      // where {page} is replaced by the page number (or use {page+1} to get a one-based index),
      // {size} is replaced by the number of records to show,
      // {sortList:col} adds the sortList to the url into a "col" array, and {filterList:fcol}
      // the filterList to the url into an "fcol" array.
      // So a sortList = [[2,0],[3,0]] becomes "&col[2]=0&col[3]=0" in the url
      // and a filterList = [[2,Blue],[3,13]] becomes "&fcol[2]=Blue&fcol[3]=13" in the url
      ajaxUrl : 'http://example.com/json.php?paged={page}&{sortList:column}',

      // use this option to manipulate and/or add additional parameters to the ajax url
      customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
          // manipulate the url string as you desire
          url += '&currPage=' + window.location.pathname;

          // trigger a custom event; if you want
          $(table).trigger('changingUrl', url);
          // send the server the current page
          return url;
      },

      // ajax error callback from $.tablesorter.showError function
      // ajaxError: function( config, xhr, settings, exception ){ return exception; };
      // returning false will abort the error message
      ajaxError: null,

      // add more ajax settings here
      // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
      ajaxObject: {
        type: 'GET', // default setting
        dataType: 'json'
      },

      // process ajax so that the following information is returned:
      // [ total_rows (number), rows (array of arrays), headers (array; optional) ]
      // example:
      // [
      //   100,  // total rows
      //   [
      //     [ "row1cell1", "row1cell2", ... "row1cellN" ],
      //     [ "row2cell1", "row2cell2", ... "row2cellN" ],
      //     ...
      //     [ "rowNcell1", "rowNcell2", ... "rowNcellN" ]
      //   ],
      //   [ "header1", "header2", ... "headerN" ] // optional
      // ]
      // OR
      // return [ total_rows, $rows (jQuery object; optional), headers (array; optional) ]
      ajaxProcessing: function(data){
        if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
          var indx, r, row, c, d = data.rows,
          // total number of rows (required)
          total = data.total_rows,
          // array of header names (optional)
          headers = data.headers,
          // cross-reference to match JSON key within data (no spaces)
          headerXref = headers.join(',').replace(/\s+/g,'').split(','),
          // all rows: array of arrays; each internal array has the table cell data for that row
          rows = [],
          // len should match pager set size (c.size)
          len = d.length;
          // this will depend on how the json is set up - see City0.json
          // rows
          for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) {
            row = []; // new row array
            // cells
            for ( c in d[r] ) {
              if (typeof(c) === "string") {
                // match the key with the header to get the proper column index
                indx = $.inArray( c, headerXref );
                // add each table cell data to row array
                if (indx >= 0) {
                  row[indx] = d[r][c];
                }
              }
            }
            rows.push(row); // add new row array to rows array
          }
          // in version 2.10, you can optionally return $(rows) a set of table rows within a jQuery object
          return [ total, rows, headers ];
        }
      },

      // Set this option to false if your table data is preloaded into the table, but you are still using ajax
      processAjaxOnInit: true,

      // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
      // possible variables: {size}, {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
      // also {page:input} & {startRow:input} will add a modifiable input in place of the value
      output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',

      // apply disabled classname (cssDisabled option) to the pager arrows when the rows
      // are at either extreme is visible; default is true
      updateArrows: true,

      // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
      page: 1,

      // Number of visible rows - default is 10
      size: 50,

      // Saves the current pager page size and number (requires storage widget)
      savePages: true,
      // Saves tablesorter paging to custom key if defined.
      // Key parameter name used by the $.tablesorter.storage function.
      // Useful if you have multiple tables defined
      storageKey: 'tablesorter-pager',

      // Reset pager to this page after filtering; set to desired page number (zero-based index),
      // or false to not change page at filter start
      pageReset: 1,

      // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed.
      // The space is made up by an empty table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
      fixedHeight: false,

      // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
      // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to
      // add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
      removeRows: false,

      // If true, child rows will be counted towards the pager set size
      countChildRows: false,

      // css class names of pager arrows
      cssNext        : '.next',  // next page arrow
      cssPrev        : '.prev',  // previous page arrow
      cssFirst       : '.first', // go to first page arrow
      cssLast        : '.last',  // go to last page arrow
      cssGoto        : '.gotoPage', // page select dropdown - select dropdown that set the "page" option

      cssPageDisplay : '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
      cssPageSize    : '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option

      // class added to arrows when at the extremes; see the "updateArrows" option
      // (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
      cssDisabled    : 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
      cssErrorRow    : 'tablesorter-errorRow' // error information row

    });

});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.29.0/js/extras/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.29.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tablesorter-ignoreRow">
      <td class="pager" colspan="5">
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th> <!-- thead text will be updated from the JSON; make sure the number of columns matches the JSON data -->
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> <!-- tbody will be loaded via JSON -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) *Edit* your posts when you want to add or change something in favour of commenting them.

Comment: Try the [build widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html#setup__object_json_file_via_ajax).

Comment: thanks for the reply Mottie.. Unfortunately, didn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry, try adapting the code from the [`ajaxProcessing` of an object](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#object).

Comment: I made the php script on the server side to do all the dirty work and form a table out of it using the tablesorter instead of making the tablesorter to load all the data and page it.

Comment: BTW, Mottie! Thanks for the AWESOME plugin!